# Simple Anti AFK AddOn

Tags: lua, macros, world-of-warcraft

I tried to write a simple LUA AddOn in World of Warcraft to avoid to be AFK.

Here is what I tried:

```
function SetNoLongerAFK()
    RunMacro("AntiAFK")
    IsPlayerAFK();
end

function IsPlayerAFK()
    while (UnitIsAFK("player") == false)    do 
        SetNoLongerAFK();
    end
end

function AntiAFKWelcomeMessage()
    print("|cff0080ffWelcome |cffd7df01"..playerName.." - "..realmName.."|r |cff0080ffto the AntiAFK AddOn!|r")
    local macroname = GetMacroInfo("AntiAFK")
    if (macroname == nil or macroname == "") then
        CreateMacro("AntiAFK", 134400, "/afk", 1)
    end
    IsPlayerAFK();
end

callWelcome();
```

but the RunMacro API Function is blocked I guess. Is there any other ways to realise this with the WoW LUA-API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [RunMacro](https://wowpedia.org/API_RunMacro) is a protected function that can only be called by user code if it was triggered by a key/button press.

Before I continue, let me say I'd be careful with attempting custom, homebrewed anti-afk methods on Blizzard's servers, as it may be seen as automation if Warden notices it.

The addon [Narcissus](https://www.curseforge.com/wow/addons/narcissus) has a feature to activate its, uh, viewport when you go AFK, and ***also*** has an option to cast /stand to prevent sitting down while AFK. The setting says it does not prevent AFK logout, but I ***feel*** like it does prolong the time until you get eventually logged out. This is merely anecdotal, and your mileage may vary.
But you could take a look at how this is implemented in the addon and experiment with it.

Comment: So if I want to realise that, I need to add a custom UI Button which I clicked after my login to call the "Anti AFK" Function right?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was unprecise. You can define the function anywhere, but it has to be _called_ in an execution path that was started by a user interaction (button press) 
So it cannot be called automatically, instead requiring user input - which would already un-AFK you. So, it's not possible to achieve what you want, at least this way.

Comment: additional clarification: I meant that the call to RunMacro has to happen in an execution path initiated by user interaction.